# How to show electrostatic interactions in Pymol or other on the wanted residue

Tags: proteins, vmd, pymol

I have the following Pymol visual,
The green molecule is receptor and red/yellow is the ligand.
In the ligand I highlighted Lysine (K) residue as yellow.

[image]

What I want to do is to highlight and draw the electro static contact of the ligand especially with Lysine residue. Like this in Pymol:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

I'm open to other solution other than Pymol, e.g. VMD.

Comment: No idea about pymol, but can give you advise in how you can get it in `VMD`. Lemme know so that I can write an answer.

Comment: @Vasista Please do. Thanks in advance. I've modified my OP to generalize.

Comment: @Vasista if you'd like to add an answer, it looks like the OP generalized the question to VMD or other software.

Comment: @Vasista The OP seems keen to learn your answer about how to do it VMD. Can you answer it? :)

Comment: @Vasista do you think you can write an answer about **how to do this in VMD**?

Comment: @littleworth if my post answers your question, please click on the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Pymol**, the polar contacts can be visualised in the following way:

1. Enable the sequence tab by clicking on : Display -> Sequence
2. Select both the protein and ligand in sequence tab
3. In the right side tab, next to the object name, click the **'A'** button -> find -> polar contacts -> then you will get a list of options which you can choose -> for example you can choose : to any atoms.

The sequence of steps shown in the below picture uses the following protein ligand combination:

- Protein : Beta chain of the Human Haemoglobin (PDB ID: 2hhb)
- Ligand:    Corresponding HEM of the beta chain

[image]

The polar contacts will be shown as yellow lines as shown in below picture:

[image]

You can replicate the same steps with your protein + ligand choose the relevant type of polar contact from the list.